# Geometrical interpretation of $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ having finite limit

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a real-valued function whose graph admits an asymptote near $+\infty$. This means there exist real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that
$$ \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) - (ax + b) = 0.$$

Under this assumption, one can check that $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ is finite and gives the slope $a$.

Conversely, if we simply assume that $f$ is a function such that $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ tends to a number $a \in \mathbf R$ as $x$ tends to $+\infty$, is it a geometrical property we can observe on the graph of $f$? The limit of $f(x) - ax$ does not necessarily exist, does it?

Comment: If $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ tends to some $a$ as $x$ grows, that means that eventually $f(x)$ is within the cone defined by the two lines $(a-\epsilon)x$ and $(a+\epsilon)x$, no matter what $\epsilon$ is (as long as it's not $0$). However, any such cover gets wider and wider, so the actual difference between $f(x)$ and $ax$ can diverge to basically anything you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct -- this is not a sufficient condition for an asymptote to exist.

For example, for
$$ f(x) = x + \sqrt x $$
the limit of $f(x)/x$ exists and is $1$, and $1$ is also the limit of $f'(x)$, but the function does not have a linear asymptote in the sense defined here.

Or even worse, consider
$$ f(x) = x+\sqrt x\sin(x) $$
where the limit of $f(x)/x$ is still $1$, but both $f'(x)$ and $f(x)-x$ make larger and larger oscillations rather than converge nicely.

---

The most you can say is that the graph will *eventually* stay within the cone
$$ \{ (x,y) \mid (a-\varepsilon)x < y < (a+\varepsilon)x \} $$
for every $\varepsilon$ (which is just a restatement of what it means for $a$ to be a limit, of course), but what *does* within that cone is entirely up in the air.